# Adobe AMS to AMS initStream method call

Tags: adobe, flash-media-server

Do any of my fellow AMF enthusiasts know of any information on the calls made by one AMS server to another AMS server? For instance, I am specifically looking for information about the arguments sent in the initStream call; this is sample data I got recently when an AMS server connected to my server:

```
Method: initStream Number of Params: 2 0: 1.7765824089018436E-307 1: null
```

A standard call from a Flash client will only contain one argument, which consists of a stream identifier. The above may also be an identifier, but its not an integer type that we normally expect. I have google'd and checked my other sources, but I'm coming up with nothing helpful.

To sum it all up, I need to know the arguments and their types which are sent when one AMS calls another AMS.

**EDIT**

After more work on this issue, the initStream method has been added to the server and the parameter #1 is assumed to be a stream id. This method is followed by createStream(0)

```
Method: createStream Num Params: 1 0: 0
```

and after that method was added, it seems that initial setup is Ok, but when following up by requesting a VOD stream on Red5 from AMS, it calls play with unexpected parameters and no stream name

```
Method: play Num Params: 23 0: 4.801834657218423E-299 1: null 2: null 3: null 4: null 5: null 6: null 7: null 8: null 9: null 10: null 11: null 12: null 13: null 14: null 15: null 16: null 17: null 18: null 19: null 20: null 21: null 22: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red5 has been modified starting at version 1.0.7-SNAPSHOT to allow these extra methods used by AMS. The "odd" play method call can be resolved by setting objectEncoding to 0 like so on your server side script (SSAS).

```
application.r5test = new NetConnection();
application.r5test.objectEncoding = 0;
```